# Pergunta removida pelo sistema

Tags: suporte

Recentemente tive uma pergunta removida automaticamente pelo sistema, "Criação de serviço web Gratuito"

Gostaria de saber se existe um meio de acessa-la

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No final da página que tem as *"minhas perguntas feitas"* há um link *perguntas recentes removidas*, aí podes encontrar perguntas como esta que foram apagadas por tí ou pelo sistema.

Fica aqui uma imagem também:

> [image: perguntas recentes removidas]

Comment: Mas é só se for recentes?

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, não sei qual é o limite de tempo a partir do qual desaparecem de vêz. Na minha conta do SOen não tenho nenhuma pergunta nesse link, o que indica que as que lá estavam desapareceram.

Comment: Pois, foi o que eu fui ver também.

Comment: Então, relacionado, eu pessoalmente não sabia, depois que comecei a pesquisar achei: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1354/como-uma-pergunta-pode-ser-exclu%C3%ADda-e-efetivamente-removida-do-site